# Swift - How to add string array to my listview in swiftUI

Tags: arrays, swiftui, swift5, swiftui-list

I have a array of string

```
fakeData = ["Array A",
            "Array B",
            "Array C",
            "Array D"]
```

How Can I implement this array in ListView in SwiftUI ?

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: Ya i tried a for each but didn't add the state I resolved my issue thanks....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you should mark the array as `State` if you are going to change the data inside the view, or leave it alone, but I choose `State` for demonstrate:

```
@State var fakeData = ["Array A", "Array B", "Array C", "Array D"]
```

Then make a list from it with just one line of code:

```
List(fakeData, id:\.self) { Text($0) }
```

---

Wrap it up:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var fakeData = ["Array A", "Array B", "Array C", "Array D"]

    var body: some View {
        List(fakeData, id:\.self) { Text($0) }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `@State` property wrapper does not have to do with "representing UI". It allows the property to be modified within the View body, and triggers a UI update when the property is changed. In other words, you can display static data without the `@State` property wrapper, and you should only include it on an array if you are dynamically adding or removing elements.

Comment: Thanks John M I didn't add @State property